# Is it possible to get a list of available layouts in rails (including those from engines)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview

I'm allowing admins to choose a different layout for their page. Right now it's just a text input and they type the name in. This means they have to know the name in advance.

If they make a typo it would raise an exception, so I am checking the layout exists by doing the following in the controller and if it doesn't exist it defaults to "application".

```
lookup_context.template_exists?(@page.layout, "layouts")
```

If I can get a list of layouts I don't need to check in the controller anymore.

I've had a look through actionview and found nothing.
I could use Dir to get a list of layout files but I need all layouts from included engines.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to generate a list of all available layouts including those from engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, all the layouts are present in the `app/views/layouts` directory. The layouts available to you by default are the files present in this directory. To get the list of layouts, try this :

```
@layouts = Dir.glob('app/views/layouts/*')
for layout in @layouts
    puts layout
end
```

If you have defined a custom path for the engines in your app as described [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html), you will have to add those layouts explicitly:

```
@layouts << Dir.glob('custom_engine_path/*')
```

Comment: Thanks, using Dir was the way we went in the end

Comment: I would suggest `Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'layouts').to_s + '/*')` to avoid relative path hassle.